# How do I get an artifact from the PR that is getting merged into master in Jenkiins

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

**Scenario:**
A developer creates a PR against the master branch.  Jenkins (Cloudbees) goes to work building and validating that PR as well as generating a text file containing a build_info.txt file as an artifact.

When the PR is merged into master I need to be able to access the artifact that was created in the PR validation step, extract the version information it contains and commit that version information into master along with PR code changes.

**Problem:**
I've printed out the env vars during the merge to master script (`run_pr_merge`), but I haven't seen information (It might be there, I just don't recognize it) that would allow me to link back to the PR job that is being merged or a way to say "give me the artifacts that were created during this PR's build and validation job"

My script looks something like this:

```
if (isMasterBranch()) {
    // run this when code is pushed to master
    sh "bash ./run_pr_merge.sh" // which requires build_info.txt from PR build
} else {
    // run this for each PR build
    sh "bash ./build_and_validate.sh"
    archiveArtifacts 'build_info.txt'
}
```

Am not super familiar with Jenkins/Cloudbees, so there might be a better way of structuring the pipeline to achieve what I need but am hoping there's a relatively easy way to get hold of the PR info being merged int master.

Have looked at copyArtifacts but again I'm not sure how to to reference the PR being merged.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [CopyArtifact](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/) plugin for Jenkins that can be used to copy artifacts from another job. It supports both "Freestyle" jobs and pipeline. You need to provide job URL, and, optionally, build number (by default it will use last successful build). You can craft the URL of the job provided you have the PR number.

In our environment, the URL for a specific job looks something like:

```
https://jenkins.mycompany.com/job/mycompany/job/myproj/job/PR-<number>/<build_no>/
```

Provided I have the PR number, I can build the needed URL with e.g.

```
def pr_number = 12345

def job_url = "https://jenkins.mycompany.com/job/mycompany/job/myproj/job/PR-${pr_number}/"

step([
                $class: 'CopyArtifact',
                filter: 'build_info.txt',
                fingerprintArtifacts: true,
                optional: true,
                projectName: job_url
                // default selector is "last successful build"
                // selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector',
                //            buildNumber: build_number]
            ])

// check the file is there
sh "cat ${WORKSPACE}/build_info.txt"
```

Comment: But the piece I'm missing is how to get the PR-number from the job that is triggered after the PR is merged into master?